# How to add items to a collection in the markup?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of items in a table I'm trying to Edit.

I have a file BankAccount.cshtml that looks like:

```
@model BankAccount

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AccountId, new { @id="accountId" } )

<table id="transactionTable">
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.InboundTransactions)
    </tbody>
</table>
<a id="addTransactionLink">Add</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#transferTable').on('click', 'a.removeLink', function (e) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        $('#addTransactionLink').click(function () {

            var transaction = {
                TransactionNumber: "234"
            };

                $.post('/BankAccount/AddRow/', transaction, function (data) {

                $('#transactionTable').append(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

A Transaction.cshtml that looks like:

```
@model Transaction

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TransactionNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="removeLink">Remove</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

So this is put in for the EditorFor InboundTransactions.

On the BankAccountController the method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult AddRow(Transaction transaction)
        {
            return PartialView("EditorTemplates/Transaction", transaction);
        }
```

So what's supposed to happen is when the add row button is clicked a new row is added.

Anyway if I go to the page and I might already have two transactions then I add a row it might look like this in the markup:

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <input id="BankAccount_Transactions_0__TransactionNumber" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="456" name="BankAccount.Transactions[0].TransactionNumber" data-val-required="The TransactionNumber field is required." data-val-number="The field TransactionNumber must be a number." data-val="true">
  </td>
  <td>
      <a class="removeLink">Remove</a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
      <input id="BankAccount_Transactions_1__TransactionNumber" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="456" name="BankAccount.Transactions[1].TransactionNumber" data-val-required="The TransactionNumber field is required." data-val-number="The field TransactionNumber must be a number." data-val="true">
  </td>
  <td>
      <a class="removeLink">Remove</a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input id="Transactions" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="0" name="Transactions">
  </td>
  <td>
     <a class="removeLink">Remove</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So you can see an obvious problem here. The newly added row does not contain info saying that it is part of the collection of transactions that belong to the BankAccount.

When a postback occurs the newly added rows aren't included.

Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you taking a look at the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for editing a variable length list. It illustrates the usage of a custom `BeginCollectionItem` helper which replaces numbered indexes in collections with Guids. This will also help you later when you start removing and adding items because you will need to resync indexes. With Guids there are no such problems.